Why is the translation of cilicio as lash justified?
The penultimate stanza in Gabriela Mistral's poem Íntima goes as follows (emphasis mine):

Porque mi amor no es sólo esta gavilla
reacia y fatigada de mi cuerpo,
que tiembla entera al roce del cilicio
y que se me rezaga en todo vuelo.

Ursula K. Le Guin translated this is follows (emphasis mine):

For my love's not just this stubborn,
weary burden of my body,
that shivers all over at the touch of the lash
and lags behind me when I fly:

(Selected Poems of Gabriela Mistral, translated by Ursula K. Le Guin. University of New Mexico Press, 2003, pages 14–15.)
For comparison, Google Translate gives the following, more literal translation (emphasis mine):

Because my love is not only this reluctant and tired sheaf of my body,
that trembles all over at the touch of the hair shirt
and that lags behind me in every flight.

A cilicio is a cilice or hair shirt, not only according to Google Translate but also to Wikipedia and other sources (ToeNexus and Cautivo Esterellay are two Spanish sources that came up in searches).
A lash has other meanings that are not directly connected with each other. Both can be used for "mortification of the flesh", but that's an indirect connection. Based on this, it looks like Le Guin makes the meaning of that line more violent than the original text. Or am I missing something?

Gabriel Mistral was writing for a Spanish-speaking audience, who are probably familiar with hairshirts and their use for mortification of the flesh. Ursula Le Guin was writing for an English-speaking audience, who may be completely unfamiliar with hairshirts, but familiar with the use of lashes for mortification of the flesh. This may be why she changed the word in translation.

@PeterShor The hairshirt is by no means exclusive to any specific Christian tradition.

@PeterShor Even the audience of The Da Vinci Code could be expected to know what a hair shirt was  ;)

El roce del cilicio is not necessarily a hairshirt. It could be the spiked belt, too. Roce is rub. The spiked belt rubs the skin when there is movement. And rezagar is to leave behind.

Real Academia Española (RAE)

m. Faja de cerdas o de cadenillas de hierro con puntas, ceñida al cuerpo junto a la carne, que para mortificación usan algunas personas.= Spiked metal belt worn at the waist or around the thigh

m. Saco o vestidura áspera que se usaba antiguamente para la penitencia. =hairshirt (animal hair) or sackcloth (made of coarse cloth)



////////////////////////////////
The first meaning in the RAE is the metal-spiked belt.
The second is like this:

A cilice /ˈsɪlɪs/, also known as a sackcloth,1 was originally a
garment or undergarment made of coarse cloth or animal hair (a
hairshirt) worn close to the skin.

Cilice on Wikipedia
flogging and penance
lash in English makes one think of whipping aka flogging. However, this cilicio is not about lashing, it's about rubbing [roce] up against the skin, which causes great discomfort to the wearer.
There is also a lash with little metal or leather balls on it with which the penitent can flog himself, known as a scourge (see previous link and this)

Suggestion for meaning:
For my love is not just the faded garland
of my weary body
trembling all over when the cilice rubs against me
and left behind when I fly.
The image here is like a cage of penitence where the speaker is tortured by this penitence instrument but from which s/he can fly way.
rezagar is to leave something behind
The Spanish says roce del cilicio which is the cilice rubbing up against the body. There are different ways to translate this but I think rezagar needs to be to leave behind.
I don't think lash works in the translation at all.
